# Deploying swing embedded javafx application with javafx maven plugin

Tags: java, swing, maven, javafx

The deployment of javafx application is very easy with the help of javafx maven plugin ([Zen java Plugin](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/)) but now in my application i required some functionality which is only available in swing and as per java 7 swing can't able to embed in javafx.
So,I need to embed the javafx in swing but while packaging i need to give the application's primary UI toolkit as Swing.So,This setting of UI toolkit is possible from javafx maven plugin.